# form.is_valid() always returns false in views.py

Tags: django

form.is_valid() always fails. I tried different ways to handle it but fails every time and it returns false. Please help in figuring out whats wrong with the code.

models.py looks like this -

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_name

class Images(models.Model):
    album_name = models.ForeignKey(Album, db_column='album_name')
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    upload_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    like_cntr = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_name
```

forms.py is -

```
class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('album_name', 'description',)
```

views.py is -

```
class RandomView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'photos/random.html'

    def get(self, request, album_name):
        images = Images.objects.filter(album_name=album_name)
        context = {'album_name':album_name, 'images' : images}
        return render(request, 'photos/random.html', context)

    def post(self, request, album_name):
        form = ImagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            text = form.cleaned_data['description']
            Images.album_name = album_name
            form.save()
        else: 
            return HttpResponse("Failed to save")
```

Templates is -

```
<h3>Album : {{album_name }}</h3>
{% for image in images %}
<img src="{{image.image.url}}" height="400" width="500">
<h4> {{image.image_name }}</h4>

<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
    <span class = "badge">Description</span>
    {% if image.description  %}
        <h4> {{image.description }} </h4>
    {% else %}
        <input type="text" value=" "/>
        <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why don't you let the form show you what is wrong, by passing it back to the template and displaying `form.errors`, target than that useless "failed to save" message?

Comment: You're not including _any_ of the image required fields on the form, so of course it isn't validating.

Comment: You should also consider letting Django render the form fields for you, instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks all..I'm new to Django and learning it. The part you have pointed out, helped me. The other issue which I face now is on the ForeignKey in ModelForm. I got a solution to use ModelChoiceField and overriding init method in forms.py. However, some issues still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your necessary name and id attributes for your input tag?

```
<input type="text" name="description" id="id_description"/>
```

Comment: Thanks all..I'm new to Django and learning it. The part you have pointed out, helped me. The other issue which I face now is on the ForeignKey in ModelForm. I got a solution to use ModelChoiceField and overriding __init__ method in forms.py. However, some issues still exists.

Comment: @Maneesha and what kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `{{ form.errors }}` above "form" tag. And first of all check that what the errors arrive. Then Find the solution based on that error. Let me know if it is helpful or not.